# For some reason csv_f.line_num is returning 0 for all entries instead of the index

Tags: python, csv, line-numbers

My code was working this morning and I made some change and cannot figure out what changed and why it is no longer working. Here is what the code currently is and it is returning an empty set. The second section after multiple lines is how I tested it to see what the mistake is, and it returns about 10,000 zeroes. I want it to add the index of each entry to the set which contains the indices so I can work with that data later.

```
  csv_f = csv.reader(f)
  for row in f:
    if row[2] == "H":
       indexofH.append((csv_f.line_num))
print(indexofH)



with open('file.csv') as f:
  csv_f = csv.reader(f)
  for row in f:
    indexofH.append((csv_f.line_num))
    if row[2] == "H":
       indexofH.append((csv_f.line_num))
print(indexofH)
```

Comment: You're iterating over the file not the reader, iterate over the reader instead: `for row in csv_f :`
 `

Comment: Will you post Iain’s suggestion in your own answer to this question, and accept your answer? It’d be good to “close” this since SO did provide a solution.

Comment: Note: `line_num` gives the line number, not the record number. If you have multi line data they will be different